# How can i add search box and overlay on app tool bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image: Skyscanner app]

In the above image of skyscanner app, when i click on the search icon then it shows as like below image.

[image]

So, how can i overlay the search layout when i click on search icon ?

Comment: i had similar need so what i did was a hackish solution, I added below views in layout file and made their visibility GONE   and when user clicks on search icon make them VISIBLE

Comment: But how you have overlay view above the app bar and have you find any other solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i have used

Create a custom layout for action bar and set it this way

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

    View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
     // find ids using view.

       imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_back);
```

In that custom layout add all views,which will be there before clicking search and after clicking search 
which every view should be visible after search icon is clicked make there visibility as GONE in XML by default,

back, California, search icon visible by default

when user click on search icon make back, California,search icon visibility GONE and make X icon and search hotels visible

Answer (score 0):

This may help you and fulfill your requirement. Although its not the perfect solution but it worked for me for setting the view above toolbar.

Use Popup window and inflate the layout of search.

Design the popupwindow location, animationstyle, background etc.. and refer this [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) for systemUiVisibility usage.

```
PopupWindow mpopup; //declare it globally.

    //it will make main background transperent. where mRoot is the root layout.
                mRoot.setAlpha(0.50f);

            View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_search,
                                null);

                        popUpView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                        // Creation of popup
                        mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
                        //this will set the transperency of background.and set the background color transperent.
                        mpopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                        //set the animation style of popup view.
                        mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
                        mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
                        FloatingActionButton btnSearch = (FloatingActionButton) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);

                        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mpopup.dismiss();
        //remove transperency 
                                mRoot.setAlpha(1f);
                            }
                        });
```

activity_search.xml:  (Design your layout according to your requirement below is just sample)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coorlay"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/textSecondary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Write something" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="check1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="check2" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="check3" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/places_ic_search"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/lay_search"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, when you click on search button of ur toolbar then the above view will display. and for background transperency of root layout you can set its alpha on buttonclick and remove alpha on button dismiss. as given in code.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i dont want solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add search option by using following piece of code and customize it a per your needs.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final android.view.Menu menu) {

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.hint_search));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

            ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
            searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search);

            SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
            searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.text));

            ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear);

            ImageView voiceIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn);
            voiceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_voice);

            voiceIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    menu.getItem(0).collapseActionView();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            menu.add(getString(R.string.title_search))
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
                    .setActionView(searchView)
                    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menu.getItem(0), new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    AppGlobal.hideSoftKeyboard(context);
                    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    searchView.requestFocus();
                    AppGlobal.openSoftKeyboard(context);
                    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use popup window or create layout inside toolbar like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="California"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="California"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/single_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="California"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/single_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="California"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="California"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_spinner"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="spinner"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="173dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Its look like this :

[image: Its look like this]

you can show/hide views based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@Dipak please follow the link [PersistentSearch](https://github.com/s7092910/PersistentSearch) this is more than you want,
I use same in my code to really awesome .